# Bootstrap navbar items not getting in center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

there is a website that I came across and I was making a clone of it using html css and bootstrap. But I am facing problems like my navbar is not working out. I need help I need to center the items in the navbar in the center and the social icons on the right side. I am new to this thing can anyone please help me?

here's the website that I am trying to make a clone of [image]

and here is my code

```css
/* #navbarNav {
  padding-bottom: 36px;
  padding-top: 54px;
} */
.nav-img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 69px;
}
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.title-div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 461px;
}
.home-heading {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: black;
}
.main-image {
  /* background-image: url(../img/ill.jpg); */
  width: 100%;
  height: 82%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.navbar {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
.navbar-brand {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}
.navbar-toggler {
  filter: invert(100%);
}
.navbar-nav li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.instagram {
  filter: invert(100%);
  padding: 6px;
}
.facebook {
  filter: invert(100%);
  padding: 6px;
}
.email {
  filter: invert(100%);
  padding: 6px;
}
.phone-call {
  filter: invert(100%);
}
/* .mid{
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 200px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 235px;
   
} */
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
}

li {
  float: left;
  /* border-right: 1px solid #bbb; */
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo {
      /* width: 133px;
    height: 69px; */
        width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 69px;
      margin-top: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    margin-left: 16px;
}
.bdy-img{
    width: 45% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-top: 96px;
    padding-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+Garamond:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


    <!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom " >
        <img class="navbar-brand nav-img" src="img/logo-nav.jpg" alt="">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center" >
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav> -->


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="img/logo-nav.jpg" class="logo"  alt="" loading="lazy" />
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
            aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <div class="cintainer-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span6" style=" float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
                        <ul class=" navbar-nav ">
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="">Shop</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" href=""> I Love Lables</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" href=""> About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" href=""> How It Works</a>
                            </li>
                            <ul class="list2">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href=""> Charities</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href=""> Sell With Us</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href=""> News</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href=""> Designers</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="list3">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href=""> Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">
                        <img src="nav-icons/instagram.png" class="instagram" width="50" height="50" alt=""
                            loading="lazy" />
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">
                        <img src="nav-icons/email.png" class="email" width="50" height="50" alt="" loading="lazy" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">
                        <img src="nav-icons/facebook.png" class="facebook" width="50" height="50" alt=""
                            loading="lazy" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">
                        <img src="nav-icons/phone-call.png" class="phone-call" width="50" height="50" alt=""
                            loading="lazy" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>


    <!-- <div class="main-bdy-div  align-items-center" >
    <div class="container-fluid title-div home-heading">
        <h1 class="" style="font-size: calc(3.6vw + 1rem); font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;" >I love labels</h1>
    </div>
           
    <div class="container-fluid title-div " style="width: 49%;   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); ">
        <h1 class="" style="text-align: justify; font-size: calc(1.44vw + 1rem); font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;">New Zealand's
        Premier Boutique for Quality Preloved Designer Fashion</h1>
    </div>
    <img class="main-image" src="img/ill.jpg" alt="">
</div> -->


    <div class="main-img">
        <img class="main-image" src="img/ill.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid justify-content-start">
        <div class="container-fluid title-div " style=" text-align: center; width: 28%;   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); ">
            <h1 class="" style="font-size: calc(3.6vw + 1rem); font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;">I love labels
            </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid title-div justify-content-between " style="width: 49%;   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); top: 576px; ">
            <h1 class=""
                style="text-align: justify; font-size: calc(1.44vw + 1rem); font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;">
                New Zealand's
                Premier Boutique for Quality Preloved Designer Fashion</h1>
        </div>
    </div>


<!-- main body section -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
        <img class="bdy-img" src="img/IMG_0018.jpg" style=" width: 100%;
  height: auto;" alt="">

        <div class="d-flex align-items-start justify-content-end">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">Our Unique Approach.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>











    <!-- bootstrap js -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please view the snippet in full page mode.

I have only tried to help in what you have asked, there are still some issues which I have not tried to solve as you are trying to learn.

Below are the changes:

1 Added `justify-content-md-center` in below tag

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
```

2 Adjusted above tag's children to have two `ul` only

3 added `ml-auto` css class in above two `ul` tags

```css
/* #navbarNav {
  padding-bottom: 36px;
  padding-top: 54px;
} */

.nav-img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 69px;
}

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.title-div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 461px;
}

.home-heading {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: black;
}

.main-image {
  /* background-image: url(../img/ill.jpg); */
  width: 100%;
  height: 82%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.navbar-nav li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.instagram {
  filter: invert(100%);
  padding: 6px;
}

.facebook {
  filter: invert(100%);
  padding: 6px;
}

.email {
  filter: invert(100%);
  padding: 6px;
}

.phone-call {
  filter: invert(100%);
}


/* .mid{
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 200px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 235px;
   
} */

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
}

li {
  float: left;
  /* border-right: 1px solid #bbb; */
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  /* width: 133px;
    height: 69px; */
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 69px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.bdy-img {
  width: 45% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  padding-top: 96px;
  padding-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+Garamond:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


  <!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom " >
        <img class="navbar-brand nav-img" src="img/logo-nav.jpg" alt="">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center" >
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav> -->


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="img/logo-nav.jpg" class="logo" alt="Logo Img" loading="lazy" />
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class=" navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Shop</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href=""> I Love Lables</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href=""> About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href=""> How It Works</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href=""> Charities</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href=""> Sell With Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href=""> News</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href=""> Designers</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href=""> Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">
            <img src="nav-icons/instagram.png" class="instagram" width="50" height="50" alt="" loading="lazy" />
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">
            <img src="nav-icons/email.png" class="email" width="50" height="50" alt="" loading="lazy" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">
            <img src="nav-icons/facebook.png" class="facebook" width="50" height="50" alt="" loading="lazy" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">
            <img src="nav-icons/phone-call.png" class="phone-call" width="50" height="50" alt="" loading="lazy" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>


  <!-- <div class="main-bdy-div  align-items-center" >
    <div class="container-fluid title-div home-heading">
        <h1 class="" style="font-size: calc(3.6vw + 1rem); font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;" >I love labels</h1>
    </div>
           
    <div class="container-fluid title-div " style="width: 49%;   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); ">
        <h1 class="" style="text-align: justify; font-size: calc(1.44vw + 1rem); font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;">New Zealand's
        Premier Boutique for Quality Preloved Designer Fashion</h1>
    </div>
    <img class="main-image" src="img/ill.jpg" alt="">
</div> -->


  <div class="main-img">
    <img class="main-image" src="img/ill.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid justify-content-start">
    <div class="container-fluid title-div " style=" text-align: center; width: 28%;   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); ">
      <h1 class="" style="font-size: calc(3.6vw + 1rem); font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;">I love labels
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid title-div justify-content-between " style="width: 49%;   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); top: 576px; ">
      <h1 class="" style="text-align: justify; font-size: calc(1.44vw + 1rem); font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;">
        New Zealand's Premier Boutique for Quality Preloved Designer Fashion</h1>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- main body section -->

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
      <img class="bdy-img" src="img/IMG_0018.jpg" style=" width: 100%;
  height: auto;" alt="">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-start justify-content-end">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Our Unique Approach.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>











  <!-- bootstrap js -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'justify-content-center' class to align list items to center:

```
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
```

and 'nav justify-content-end' to align items to right:

```
<ul class="nav justify-content-end">
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navs/

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out with this.